# Can't read peer records

Tags: c#, p2p, peer, pnrp

I'm using this code for reading peer data and comments:

```
public Dictionary<int, string> ResolvePeerMethod()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> peerInfo = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    int count = 0;
    string[] peerinfo = new string[1];
    PeerNameResolver resolver = new PeerNameResolver();
    PeerName peerName123 = new PeerName("peer id");

    PeerNameRecordCollection results = resolver.Resolve(peerName123);

    foreach (PeerNameRecord record in results)
    {
        if (record.Comment != null)
        {
            peerinfo[0] = record.Comment;
            peerInfo.Add(0, peerinfo[0]);
        }
        if (record.Data != null)
        {
            peerinfo[1] = (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(record.Data));
            peerInfo.Add(1, peerinfo[1]);
        }
    }

    return peerInfo;
}
```

This should return a dictionary with data and comment, but it just skips the code because it doesn't find any record in the peer. Running the same code in a console works. The `peer id` is correct; I've checked it several times.

Comment: You're saying `resolver.Resolve(peerName123)` returns an empty collection and the `foreach` block is never entered?  By the way, just a note on style, that is quite confusing to have two variables whose names only differ by case, especially when it's only the letter `I`/`i` that differs.  It seems like `peerinfo` could be replaced by a scalar `string` scoped to the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @BACON yes it returns a record without values